# How can I check the status of a moderator chat flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, chat, chat-flags

I just raised a custom mod flag on a chat message and was wondering if there was a way to see that status of this flag, or if it was marked as helpful or declined.

Comment: The flag will usually be handled before it's read